# How to remain at a scroll position in RecyclerView after adding items at its first index and call notifydatasetchange

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I am using a RecyclerView, I add items before the first item, the scroll position moves up to the newly first item added. How can I maintain my scroll position after adding new items at its first index and call `notifydatasetchange()` ?

this is what i do in my adapter

```
    mCurrentFragment.items.addAll(0, createLineItems(dataArrayList));

    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: you can calculate it from the ammount of items you inserted and set scroll value manually

Comment: ok i will try it , thx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two options:

1. **Use the more sophisticated versions of `notify`**

   ```
   List newData = createLineItems(dataArrayList);
   mCurrentFragment.items.addAll(0, newData);
   notifyItemRangeInserted(0, newData.size());
   ```
2. **Use stable IDs**. On your adapter override `public long getItemId (int position)` to make it return **MEANINGFUL** values and call `setHasStableIds(true);` on it.

Comment: @Budius What do you mean by MEANINGFUL? does it mean a unique id related to each item?

Comment: @HamzehSoboh I meant exactly that. If your IDs are just the position (for example) it won't work. It must be (for example) the user ID, or the   photo ID, so when the views position changes the ID remains bounded to the data

Comment: It worked on `notifyItemRangeInserted` but not `setHasStableIds` although `getItemId` was returning `getTime()` for that item's date, which is unique.