# RecyclerView - adding first item and keeping current position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView bounded to [CursorRecyclerAdapter](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b). When im adding an item to the start of the collection (by **notifyItemInserted(0)**) the list behaves as follows :

1. When the UI is left untouched, there is an animation that moves the list to the start. meaning, shows the newly added item.
2. When the RecyclerView was scrolled down, there is an animation that moves the list one item forward.

I would like the RecyclerView keep the exact the position. Without any animation or flickering.

I tried the following solution - [How to remain at a scroll position in RecyclerView after adding items at its first index and call notifydatasetchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012391/how-to-remain-at-a-scroll-position-in-recyclerview-after-adding-items-at-its-fir) - but it didn't work.

I'd really appreciate any help here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: why do you call `notifyItemInserted` at all?

Comment: @pskink cause the first item type is not taken from db. it is saved on the adapter as an object.

Comment: tried `notifyDataSetChanged` ?

Comment: @pskink yes. same result.